# How to resolve a google mail error "The SMTP server requires secure connection or the client was not authenticated"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

```cs
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sendemail@gmail.com");
mailMessage.To.Add("receiveemail@mydomain.com");
mailMessage.Subject = "New Enquiry" ;

mailMessage.Body = "<b>Sender Name : </b>" + txt_name.Text + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Contact Number : </b>" + txt_number.Text + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Sender Email : </b>" + txt_email.Text + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Details : </b>" + txt_message.Text;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;


SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = 
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendemail@gmail.com", "Password");
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

Response.Write("<Script>alert('Thanks for contact us,our team will be contact you as soon as possible')</Script>");

txt_name.Text = "";
txt_email.Text = "";
txt_number.Text = "";
txt_message.Text = "";
```

This is my ASP.NET C# code for sending emails through the website's **contact us** page. But Google has discontinued the less secure app access option as of May 30, 2022 due to security reasons. So now I'm not able to send emails using the above code.

Less Secure app access snapshot:

[image: Less Secure app access snapshot]

How can I deal with this so I can send email again?

Comment: Maybe Tls version problem, try this in your code : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Please use another email services like AWS Email Service. Ask infra team for help u setup this

Answer (score 17):

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

> from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party
> apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using
> only your username and password.
>
> Important: This deadline does not apply to Google Workspace or Google
> Cloud Identity customers. The enforcement date for these customers
> will be announced on the Workspace blog at a later date.

Now you can manage Apps password:

1. Go to Gmail account settings , and click on security tab
2. add 2 step verification (if you don't have)
3. click on "App Password"
4. select application device or add new one
5. you will get new password to use in your app

change the email password in your app , and try to send emails

Comment: I don't see an "App Password" section within the security tab. Is it listed as something else?

Comment: @FunnerSoft you need to add 2 step verification before

Comment: This is working. I created new App Password & used the new one in my SMTP Settings.

Comment: I am a super admin and also the only user for a google domain. I am encountering the exact issue described in this thread

https://support.google.com/a/thread/121055581/infinite-loop-login-on-google-account-for-2-step-verification?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=637898906542534888-4241937359&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en

This appears to be blocking me from being able to solve this SMTP issue =/

Comment: For anyone else coming here. If you are a super admin of a google domain, and you cannot add 2 factor like my previous thread above mentioned. It's because you need to allow it's usage within your domain. This thread explains how.

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/googleapps/204404084/how-do-i-enable-2-step-verification-for-google-workspace

Doing that will then let you use the "App Password" for this solution

Comment: @NajiMakhoul solution worked for me to find "App Password" option.

Comment: after setting up app password i still get this smtp exception 5.7.0 any idea? although i receive emails

Comment: What if the sender of the email should change? will it require me to change the security settings of all those email addresses?